# Run functions with checkbox interactions

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create checkboxes that will add an object to an array when checked, but will remove that object when unchecked. I am not sure if this is the correct way, but will show what I have below. Using Angular 2 by the way.

Original Code:

```
  <div>
   <ul>
    <a *ngFor="let perkResult of perkList.results" (click)="onAddPerk(perkResult)">
     <li>{{ perkResult.perk }}</li>
     </a>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let perk of company.perks;>
     {{ perk.perk }}
    <a (click)="onDeletePerk(i)"></a>
  </div>
```

Functions:

```
 onAddPerk(perkResult) {
    // Adds a new perk to the array
  this.company.perks.push({perk: (perkResult.perk)});
 }

 onDeletePerk(i: number) {
   // Delete the perk in the selected index
   this.company.perks.splice(i, 1);
 }
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
  <div *ngFor="let benefitResult of benefitList.results" >
     <a (click)="onAddBenefit(benefitResult)">
      <input type="checkbox"  />   
     //Basically if checked then run add function, if not checked then run delete function
     </a> {{ benefitResult.benefit }}
   </div>
```

EDIT:

Got to this point, but cannot reference my other scope for the delete.

```
  <ul *ngIf="benefitList">
   <div *ngFor="let benefitResult of benefitList.results; let i = index" >
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateBenefits($event, benefitResult, i)" >
     <li>
      {{ benefitResult.benefit }}
     </li>
     </div>
    </ul>


  //Original delete
  <div *ngFor="let benefit of company.benefits; trackBy: customTrackBy; let i = index">
    {{benefit.benefit}}
     <a (click)="onDeleteBenefit(i)"></a>
   </div>

 //function
  updateBenefits(event, benefitResult, i) {
   if(event.srcElement.checked) {
    this.company.benefits.push({benefit: (benefitResult.benefit)});
   } else {
    this.company.benefits.splice(i, 1);
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `change` event on the checkboxes. Then pass the event along with the object and index to a method that will look at the status of the checkbox element.

In the component:

```
optionsList = {
    results: [{
        perk: 'free coffee',
        checked: false
    }, {
        perk: 'car',
        checked: false
    }, {
        perk: 'pastry',
        checked: false
    }, {
        perk: 'free post-it notes',
        checked: false
    }]
};

updatePerks(event, perkResult) {
    perkResult.checked = event.srcElement.checked;
}
```

In your HTML template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let listItem of optionsList.results">
        <label><input type="checkbox" (change)="updatePerks($event, listItem)">
        {{ listItem.perk }}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note: I don't know your data structure, so make the necessary adjustment or post a data sample if you need more help.

Comment: So it doesn't look like I am able to delete. I think I am hitting a different scope. How would I reference that? I'll add my current code in an edit

Comment: I think the reason is that I am pushing an object from a different array into the company array. So when I want to delete, I need to be deleting from the company one rather than the other list.

Comment: I get it. this.company.perks.splice is not working because the index is the one from the other list. You could just have one list of objects and each object has a "checked" property. I'll post an example.